# 500 internal server error php/javascript/ajax

Tags: ajax

I uploaded my project to my hosting provider. Doing so has lead to an error in a JavaScrript file. This JavaScript is needed, because I render an alert that shows the data that JavaScript fetches, but it not sending the GET response to another file `tracker.php` which insert it into the database. the GET response is sending via AJAX. i m getting 500 internal server error. Are the any visible errors in code that could be causing this:

```
function getXMLHTTPObject() {
    var xmlHttp;

    try {
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 

    catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } 

        catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } 

            catch (e) {
                // alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return xmlHttp;
}

function trackMe() {
    var xmlHttp = getXMLHTTPObject();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4) {
        var response=xmlHttp.responseText;
        alert(response);
    }
}

var data;
data="appName="+ navigator.appName;
data+="&appVersion="+ navigator.appVersion;
data+="&appCodeName="+ navigator.appCodeName;
data+="&platform="+ navigator.platform;
data+="&oscpu="+ navigator.oscpu;
data+="&cookieEnabled="+ navigator.cookieEnabled;
data+="&language="+ navigator.language;
data+="&vendor="+ navigator.vendorSub;
data+="&vendorSub="+ navigator.vendor;
data+="&product="+ navigator.product;
data+="&productSub="+ navigator.productSub;
data+="&res="+(window.screen.width+"x"+window.screen.height);
data+="&url="+document.location.href;
data+="&referrer="+document.referrer;
data+="&uid=4bcc7d93e1b66";
xmlHttp.open("GET","tracker.php?"+data,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
//xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
//xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
//xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
alert(data);
//xmlHttp.send(data);
}
```

the same js work well on my localhost and a free hosting. but here i get error...

```
server error log-
[Fri Apr 29 04:21:31 2011] [error] [client 117.199.154.173] File does not exist: /home/abhiguru/public_html/project/500.shtml, referer: /project.php
[Fri Apr 29 04:19:33 2011] [error] [client 117.199.154.173] File does not exist: /home/abhiguru/public_html/project/500.shtml, referer: /project.php
[Fri Apr 29 04:19:04 2011] [error] [client 117.199.154.173] File does not exist: /home/abhiguru/public_html/project/500.shtml, referer: /project.php
```

the js file is located at http://project.abhiguru.in/project.php

The same js file and the tracker.php works well on free hosting here http://abhidha.serw5.com/project.php

There is no permission problem as I ran 755 on the file.
Fireug also says 500 internal server error.

Comment: A 500 internal server error is an error that occurs on the server. It's hard to say what's going wrong without knowing anything about your server. Try debugging by commenting out the whole code in tracker.php and just add a a `print 'foo';` or something to see if the connection is actually working. When encountering errors like these, take your app apart and test it step by step until you find the faulty component. Also check the servers error log and/or PHP error log if you have access to it.

Comment: The error isn't in your JavaScript. Either your PHP script is causing the error or, more likely, you have an `.htaccess` file attempting to do something it's not allowed to do

Comment: thanks... its solved... mod_security problem...